# Avoid a repeated scope variable in different controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got few controllers working with different templates:

```
curryApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'table_index.html',
            controller: 'CurryListCtrl'
        }).
        when('/cities/:cityId/', {
            templateUrl: 'template-total.html',
            controller: 'CurryDetailCtrl'
        }).
        when('/cities/:cityId/mobile/', {
            templateUrl: 'template-mobile.html',
            controller: 'CurryMobileCtrl'
        }).
        when('/cities/:cityId/online/', {
            templateUrl: 'template-online.html',
            controller: 'CurryOnlineCtrl'
        }).
```

All of theses controllers have $scope variable called `cities`
For example, the first one:

```
curryControllers.controller('CurryDesktopCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$route',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $route) {
    $scope.cityId = $routeParams.cityId;
    $http.get('json/cities.json').success(function (data) {
      $scope.cities = data;
      ...
```

The second one:

```
curryControllers.controller('CurryOnlineCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$route',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $route) {
    $scope.cityId = $routeParams.cityId;
        $http.get('json/cities.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.cities = data;
        ...
```

Is it okay to have repeated $scope variables in different controllers?
How should I refactor the code in order to escape duplicates?

Comment: use can *controller As* syntax and make alias of the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a factory:

```
.factory('citiesFactory', function($http) {
   function getCities(){
      // return promise from function
      return $http.get("json/cities.json");
   }

   return {
      getCities: getCities
   }
});
```

then in your controller:

```
curryControllers.controller('CurryDesktopCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$route', 'citiesFactory'
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $route, citiesFactory) {
    $scope.cityId = $routeParams.cityId;
    citiesFactory.getCities().then(function(response){
       $scope.cities = response.data;
    });
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If cities are not going to change for every controller use services like below

Your service should look like below

```
 app.service('myService',function($http,$q){
      var cities=null;
      this.getCities=function()
                     {

                         var deferred = $q.defer()
                         if(this.cities==null){
                         $http.get('json/cities.json')
                         .then((response) => {deferred.resolve(response);cities=response;})
                         .catch((error) => deferred.reject(error))
                         }
                         else { deferred.resolve(cities)}
                         return deferred.defer  

                     })
        });
```

Use the above service in the controller

```
  app.controller('ctrl',function($scope,myService){
           myService.getCities().then(function(data){ $scope.cities = data;})
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do create a factory like this. Forgive the syntax, but you get the idea.

```
app.factory('Cities', function ($http) {
return {
    'getData': function() {
         $http.get('json/cities.json').success(function (data) {
           return data;
          }
          .error(function(error){
           return [];
          }
    }
};
```

}]);

and in your controller inject the factory and get the data

```
curryControllers.controller('CurryOnlineCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$route', 'Cities'
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $route) {
    $scope.cityId = $routeParams.cityId;
    $scope.cities = Cities.getData();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cities json is common for all the controllers.

One option would be to move the common object used across controllers into rootscope [refer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope).

Other option would be to store the cities json in the service itself read [here](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services).